# LL(1) grammar for boolean expression

Tags: ll-grammar

I have a Boolean expression for example `(var1 = 10 and var2 > 5) or var3 < 100`.

I want to write an algorithm for syntax checking but I need to build the grammar first and then I need to construct a parse table.

Can anyone please give a clue on the grammar?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at a grammar yourself?

Comment: Can you provide more examples of what sorts of expressions are permitted?

Comment: one example of the expression would be  (var1 = 100 or var2 => 5  ) and var3 < 5000

Comment: another example is var1 like 'ABC%' and VAR2 != 5

Comment: Are you just checking syntax, or do you need a parse tree? Also, does it have to be an LL(1) parser?

Comment: yes , i just need to check syntax. that's all

Comment: yes i am assembly language coder thus iterative method is preferable!